# Any online Text File sync with desktop

Tags: backup, sync, text-editors

I want to have one text file on desktop which remain sync online and it saves its content automatically rather than i have to press save manually . Just like Google docs does . But i it on desktop so that i can open easily

Answer (score 3):

Dropbox.  By default Dropbox only syncs files in the Dropbox folder but there are ways around this - [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/#!5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder)

Alternatively, Wuala lets you sync any folder I believe but is not so easy to setup (from what I have heard)

Comment: Dropbox is indeed the most straightforward way, IMO.  It seems to me that the easiest workaround here is to save the file in the Dropbox folder and create a shorcut to said file on the Desktop.

Comment: i have windows 7 , and i have created the dektop shortcut . put when i try to pin that shortcut on taskbar then it opens new notepad file not that file